# Passing information to Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I have this
stripe

```
.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {

  payment_method: {
     metadata: {
        order_id: $("#Or_Id").val()
     },
    billing_details: {
        address: {
            city: $("#BillingCity").val(),
            country: $("#BillingCountry").val(),
            line1: $("#BillingAddress1").val(),
            line2: $("#BillingAddress2").val(),
            postal_code: $("#BillingPostCode").val(),
            state: null
        },
        email: $("#CustomerEmail").val(),
        name: $("#BillingFirstNames").val() + " " + $("#BillingSurname").val(),
        phone: $("#BillingPhone").val()
    },
    description: $("#Or_Id").val(), 
    card: card  
  }

})
```

I have three questions

1. When you go into the Stripe Dashboard the Phone numbner that is being passed isn't showing up - why?
2. When you go into the Stripe Dashboard the Order Number that is being passed isn't showing up - why?
3. How do you pass a description as Stripe isn'te recognising "description" in

description: $("#Or_Id").val(),

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer to 1 and 2 is that all those properties are being set on the PaymentMethod, not the PaymentIntent. [Billing details](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-billing_details) and [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-metadata) when added in this way will be on the PaymentMethod object rather than the PaymentIntent.

For 3, you need to set a description on the [PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update#update_payment_intent-description) server side, not on the client.

Comment: Just been told by Stripe that they don't display the Phone number in the Dashboard it is just in their Logs and it is being passed ok. and She thinks the Order Id value should have single quotes round it and I should be using statement_desriptor: not description:. I will find out when I try it later. Thanks for answering.